# Tag Synonyms For New Redundant Tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I recently noticed the [code-generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-generation) tag, which is a redundant with [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf).  I'd suggest that code-generation is a synonym of metagolf, but don't have the rep to do so.

Since there's only one question tagged code-generation, I'm tempted to just retag it.  Is that the appropriate action?  It seems strange to me that if somebody makes up a tag, others must get reputation in it to point out that it's redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's [only one question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17417/generate-a-self-extractor-application) using the [code-generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-generation) tag, and since it clearly falls under [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf), you should just retag it.  There's not much point in creating a tag synonym for a single-question tag, at least unless you anticipate the tag getting more use in the future.

That said, dmckee does make a good point that [code-generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-generation) could potentially apply to non-golf challenges too.  I don't think we need both, but I *could* support renaming [metagolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/metagolf) to [code-generation](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-generation) instead to make it more generic.  (That could also be done manually — it's only four questions plus the tag wiki.)

Answer (score 0):

> I recently noticed the code-generation tag, which is a redundant with metagolf.

I'd say that this statement constitutes a claim that there no possible way to write a code generation challenge where the goal something other than golfing the generated code, does it not?

Give me a couple of days. I'll think about it.

Comment: I agree that metagolf is a proper subset of code-generation.  However, the sole problem under the code-generation tag is metagolf.

Comment: FWIW, my comment is more general: does the synonym reputation requirement make sense in the context of a new, redundant tag?